# Set time and speed complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I am brushing up algorithms and data structures and have a few questions as well as statements I would like you to check.

**ArrayList** - O(1) (size, get, set, ...), O(n) - add operation.
**LinkedList** -  all operation O(1) (including add() ), except for retrieving n-th element which is O(n). I assume size() operation runs in O(1) as well, right?

**TreeSet** - all operations O(lg(N)). size() operation takes O(lg(n)), right?

**HashSet** - all operations O(1) if proper hash function is applied.
**HashMap** - all operations O(1), anologous to HashSet.

Any further explanations are highly welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have such magic HashSet, why do you need ArrayList?

Comment: @Stas: Because a List and a Set aren't the same thing, and also because the constant factors can still be significantly different...

Comment: @Stas: The order only gives you an idea of how the operation scales.  It won't tell you the factor e.g. HashSet can be many times slower than ArrayList and doesn't have get()/set() methods.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, @Jon Skeet You are right. Thats why I think such compassion is misleading.

Comment: @Stas: they're only misleading if you don't understand big-O notation. I see no evidence of anyone here being misled or confused.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Ok. Probably, I was wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ArrayList.add()` is *amortized* O(1). If the operation doesn't require a resize, it's O(1). If it *does* require a resize, it's O(n), but the size is then increased such that the next resize won't occur for a while.

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

The documentation is generally pretty good for Java collections, in terms of performance analysis.

The O(1) for hash algorithms isn't a matter of just applying a "proper" hash function - even with a very good hash function, you could still happen to get hash collisions. The *usual* complexity is O(1), but of course it can be O(n) if *all* the hashes happen to collide.

(Additionally, that's counting the cost of hashing as O(1) - in reality, if you're hashing strings for example, each call to `hashCode` may be O(k) in the length of the string.)

Comment: +1: Similarly, LinkedList is O(1) provided it doesn't trigger a GC, which it is more likely to do. ;)

Comment: @Suraj: GC = "garbage collection" (?)

Comment: @Suraj, LinkedList.add() always creates an object and it consumes more memory than ArrayList. So while on paper ArrayList will have delays LinkedList doesn't have, it's more less likely to trigger some of the longest delays of all.

Comment: @peter, i wont say that its as bad as to cause a GC by its own, until you are really creating a DB in ur jvm, but u have a got a point nonetheless

Comment: One more point regarding `HashSet` and `HashMap.add`: their complexity is also affected by the hashing function (which is likely O(k) where k is the string length).

Comment: @mik01aj: Thanks, have added a bit more.

Answer (score 11):

Visit the following links. It will help you getting your doubts cleared.

- [Data structures & their complexity](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223104325/http://essays.hexapodia.net/datastructures)
- [Java standard data structures Big O notation](http://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/)